# Why doesn't Eclipse detect new onClick method I've added in my layout file

Tags: android, eclipse, onclick

Here is my full layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:onClick="showButtons"
            android:text="@string/buttons_label" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="showSpinners"
        android:text="@string/spinners_label" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is where I call showSpinners:

```
private void showSpinners(View clickedButton){
        goToActivity(SpinnerActivity.class);
}
```

Eclipse underlines in yellow showSpinners by saying it's never used locally, my guess is it is not detecting my onClick attribute in the layout file.
I'm wondering why it just wont work and what I should do to make it work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the your method to :

```
public void showSpinners(View clickedButton) {
    // do the work
}
```

The method needs to be visible outside the class ([source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3aonClick)).

Comment: meh I hate beginning to code in a new language, so many noobish errors X_X, thanks.

Comment: @DominicGrenier We've all been there.  Please accept if this fixed it.